# Update Treeview dataSource on drag and drop?

Tags: treeview, kendo-ui

I'll keep the question below, but if anybody else has this problem the issue was a bug in kendo and has been fixed in the most recent version. So the solution is to update to the latest kendo release.

---

I've been trying to find a good way of listing all of the nodes in a kendo-ui treeview, and have managed to put together a pretty solid way of doing so. First I define the dataSource, for the sake of simplicity let's say:

```
data = [
    {text:element1, items:[
        {text:element2},
        {text:element3}]},
    {text:element4}]
```

Then, I set the data source as an observableHierarchy:

```
my_treeview.setDataSource(kendo.observableHierarchy(data));
```

When I want to access the list of nodes, I can get a JSON object with:

```
my_treeview.dataSource.data().toJSON();
```

This works well; it produces a correct, properly-formatted JSON object. If I call JSON.stringify on the above, I get:

```
[{"text":"element1","items":[{"text":"element2","items":[]},{"text":"element3","items":[]}]},{"text":"element4","items":[]}]
```

However, when I enable drag and drop on my tree and drag an element into a different parent, it disappears from the json output. For example, if I drag element3 into element4, the json object returned is:

```
[{"text":"element1","items":[{"text":"element2","items":[]}]},{"text":"element4","items":[]}]
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
data = [
    {text:element1, items:[
        {text:element2}]}
    {text:element4}]
```

The table's display remains correct, however, with element 3 appearing to be a child of element4. So my question is, how can I get the dataSource to update properly with drag & drop?

Comment: If you have your problem solved, post the solution as an answer then accept it instead of updating the main post with it.

Comment: Sorry, good idea. It's been awhile, but I'll go ahead and do that in case anybody has the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody else has this problem, the issue was a bug in kendo which has been fixed in the most recent version. So the solution is to update to the latest kendo release.